# How can I get sharepoint calendar and contact lists to read & write in Outlook?

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, error, calendar

How can I get sharepoint calendar and contact lists to read & write in Outlook?

Specifics:

1) I am running sharepoint services 3.0 on a Windows 2003 Small Business Server

2) I am able to read and write (create/copy) new contacts in outlook 2010 (to sharepoint)

3) Outlook 2003 users get the following message "windows sharepoint services folders are read-only in outlook"

4) Outlook 2007 users do not get an error when adding or copying new contacts but then send/receive produces errors like:

Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x80004005) : 'An error occurred in this SharePoint List. Try updating the folder again. If the problem continues, contact the SharePoint site administrator.  HTTP 500.

The server returned the following error message: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.'

I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

For the read/write operations that are not supported out of the box, you could write VBA macros that consume Web services.

There's an example here:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-to-outlook-via-web-services-and-vba.aspx